# Selected mysqli rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What I'm trying to do here is return a json_encode message if there's selected rows in my query. I tried to used num_rows() or mysqli_num_rows() but it also not working. I want to return a "failed" console message if there's no selected rows. And my array if there's a record selected in my query. Any help?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['code'])) {
    include('connect.php');
    $code= $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['code']);

    $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM list WHERE pr='$code'");
    while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())
    {
      $pr= $row['pr'];
      $approved= $row['approved'];
      $requested = $row['requested'];
    }
    if($row->affected_rows >= 1) {
        echo json_encode(array("pr" => $pr,"approved" => $approved, "requested" => $requested));
    } else {
        echo json_encode("failed");  
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: there's no sense using `->affected_rows`, its a SELECT statement, just use `->num_rows`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$userInput = $_POST['code'];

if(isset($userInput)) {
  require('connect.php');
  $code = $mysqli->real_escape_string($userInput);
  $sql  = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM list WHERE pr='".$code."'");

  if(!empty($sql)) {
    while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())
    {
      $pr        = $row['pr'];
      $approved  = $row['approved'];
      $requested = $row['requested'];
    }
    echo json_encode(["pr" => $pr, "approved" => $approved, "requested" => $requested]);
  }
  else echo json_encode("failed");
}
```

Comment: Try this and let me know

Comment: Same output. "failed" message

Comment: **try this** `$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM list WHERE pr='".$code."'");`

Comment: I already figure out the problem. I will accept your answer for the help. I'll post a new question about my new problem. Thanks